# Importing tkinter on local python installation: If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tkinter, installation, local

I need to run a python code using a local python 3.5 installation (I have no access to the system administration and the main system uses python 2.7). I managed to install python and I also downloaded the latest version tcl/tk from here http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html which I managed to configure and install correctly on a local path.

After installing tcl/tk I run the python configure again and installed again since I read somewhere that that should fix it but I'm still getting this error.

```
File "/local/path/to/python3.5/python/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Any ideas what I need to do to make it work?

Comment: have you tried searching this site for "No module named '_tkinter'"? There are literally dozens of results.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did but my situation is very specific in that I need to do everything locally. Most of the solutions are just to install dependencies system-wide in a regular way. Anyways, I already managed to do it using the solution I described below which is not exactly the local solution but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this issue by using this small Arch Linux distro that you can run locally. Very useful for when you don't have root access!

https://github.com/fsquillace/junest

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to install the `python3-tk` package through the Ubuntu package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Before this, `import tkinter` raised the same error you are seeing. Afterwards, it worked without issue.

Comment: I can't do that because I have so system root privileges so I need to use a local installation of tk and I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: @Atirag Sorry, I missed that. In that case, you could try one of the methods suggested here: http://askubuntu.com/a/350/396191. I have already tried the `dpkg -i package.deb --force-not-root --root=$HOME` method, and you still need root access even with the `--force-not-root` flag, but I have not tried the other methods.

Comment: The juju suggestion on that link worked for me. Thanks!